# How to display the menu content of mobile view navbar to center in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am getting text left aligned when in mobile view.This is done in bootstrap4. How to center the menu contents on collapse
[image]

```
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link color-me" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link color-me" href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link color-me" href="#services">Services</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link color-me" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link color-me" href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use a utility class on the `ul` or the `li` to center the text on the appropriate screen size like this one:

`.text-center` and `.text-md-left`

Comment: Yes. If only width  `ul` and `li` is more than that of the text. Otherwise, it has no effect.

Comment: @mahan Yep, but based on the limited knowledge of the situation in the question, I can't really expand too much. They could also add `.w-100` to the items to ensure this code worked if they faced that issue.